# regex css ignore certain URL type

Tags: css, regex, expression

I've created a style sheet for Twitch, but I want it ignored when I view a profile page on Twitch. The generic URL format is: http://www.twitch.tv/USERNAME/profile so I want my style to not apply when it sees a URL of that type, i.e. a streamer's profile page. What I've got so far, and doesn't work:

@-moz-document regexp('[http://www\.twitch\.tv/(?!profile)](http://www%5C.twitch%5C.tv/(?!profile)).*') {...}

The USERNAME doesn't matter, but I need to account for it in the expression, how do I do that?

Comment: This is a regex issue...not a CSS one.

Answer (score 0):

```
@-moz-document regexp("http:\/\/www\.twitch\.tv\/(?!.+\/profile).*") {
/* ... */
}
```

`(?!.+\/profile).*` matches any string or no string at all, but won't match `<anything>/profile`.

Take a look at [working regexp](http://regexr.com/3cqpe).